# Letter in Javascript Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a pattern in javascript, like this:

```
/evilExternalJS/i
```

It seems that I will match a string cotains 'evilExternalJS', but what does the '//' mean? And what does the 'i' for?

Also found another javascript regular expression like this:

```
var re = /\w+\s/g;
```

Seems that these two have the same format of '/String/Letter'. Can someone offer some detailed explanation?

Comment: The references for the various regex patterns can be found here: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions in most languages require a delimiter to mark the beginning and ending. In Javascript this is the slash character, meaning the actual regular expression is between the slashes. After the last slash, you can put some flags influencing behaviour of the regexp engine, in your examples the `i` for case-insensitive matching, and the `g` for global matching.

I would recommend [reading this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for a full introduction to these basics. The Javascript implementation is [explained here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) including the mode flags.

Comment: Regex not require to mark the beginning and the ending with delimiters..the implémentation of regex require not regex..eg: .NET

Comment: Amended it a bit, most languages like PHP, Perl etc. do. In .NET the flags are supplied separately, and the regexp is part of a string, so it's automatically delimited. PHP on the other hand goes for the double approach, requiring delimiters even within a string.

Comment: If I want to match a script's pattern like "http://example.com/unique.js", what's the pattern of it is format '/string/letter' ?

Comment: `/example\/unique\.js/`. No flags needed, but do need to escape the `.` and `/` as they represent 'any character' and 'delimiter' in the regexp respectively.